# Is Housesitting Or Petsitting Working?

Tags: work, pets, working-visas

I have registered with the company at www.trustedhousesitters.com .  I could in the future either be doing house sitting or pet sitting or both, at people's homes.  Often, the locations are in various foreign countries to mine.

My question is: Is doing the above classed as doing work?  Or in other terms, for foreign sittings, and if applicable, would someone have to obtain a work visa or permit to do it alone?  Presuming that no monies are usually exchanged between the householders and the sitter as is often the case.  Hosts usually give sitters some tasks to do.

Clarifications on this will be helpful, and which countries have any known specific rules too. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39223/discussion-on-question-by-christopher-wright-is-housesitting-or-petsitting-worki).

Comment: The answer is going to depend massivley on 1. By who? (eg Tax, Immigration, Neighbours etc) and 2. Where? (eg what country). It may also change if the person whose house you are sitting is paying for your food etc.